# PHP CLI under Windows - how did it get in PATH?

Tags: php, windows-7, command-line-interface

I'm using WAMP and there I have PHP 5.4.x - under CLI I realized I have PHP 5.3.x (php --version shows 5.3.5). I checked the environment variables but for the declared PATH there is nothing related to PHP. Any ideas how to figure out which executable and why is referenced in the CMD (I probably have installed a package long time ago and forgot about it)?

It's Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this

```
php -r "for(;;) sleep(1);"
```

in your cmd and then use the task manager to find the `php.exe` and open the properties.

There you should able to find the path of the executable.

[image: screenshot]